# Can't change date and time in Fedora 19

Tags: date-time, fedora

I am using Fedora 19 and want to change the date and time in my system. To do so, I clicked on the date and time settings, but the window does not appear. Similarly, I can't change Network Settings because the window does not open. The same is the case for proxy settings in Google Chrome. I have tried this a number of times by restarting the system, but the same problem appears every time. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you open a terminal?  Which desktop environment are you using?  Gnome?  Mate?

Comment: Yeah, I can open terminal. Using Gnome

Comment: What happens when you execute 'gnome-control-center' from a terminal?

Comment: @rickhg12hs You can see it here http://pastebin.com/LqAQDbN7

Comment: Interesting samba client dependency problems.  Are you having any samba problems?  What's the output of 'uname -a'?  Do 'yum update' and 'yum check' complete without error?  What happens when you execute 'gnome-control-center datetime'?

Comment: Would this be better answered on the Stack Exchange Superuser site?